# Jolt Transformation Spec for array of arrays

Tags: java, json, jolt

I hava a json input and expected output is below. please help me in generating the spec.

Input JSON:

```
{  
    "Features": [    
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "featureName"
        },
        {
          "name": "featureVersion"
        },
        {
          "name": "featureLevel"
        },
        {
          "name": "featureComponent"
        }
      ],
      "rows": [
        [
          "checkoutandopeninnative",
          "11R1",
          "1.0.0",
          "CheckoutAndOpenInNative",
          "1.0"
        ],
        [
          "ConfigurationMigration",
          "1.0",
          "1.0.1.68",
          "ConfigMigrationUtility",
          "1.0"
        ]
      ]
    ]    
}
```

Expected Output JSON:

```
 {
      "Features": [
        {
          "featureName": "checkoutandopeninnative",
          "featureVersion": "11R1",
          "featureLevel": "1.0.0",
          "featureComponent": "CheckoutAndOpenInNative"
        },
        {
          "featureName": "ConfigurationMigration",
          "featureVersion": "1.0",
          "featureLevel": "1.0.1.68",
          "featureComponent": "ConfigMigrationUtility"
        }
      ]
}
```

please help me with the spec to convert it in jolt. Am very new to jolt and few tried didnt work.

Thanks,
Hari

Comment: Syntax: Consecutive square brackets [[[ are wrong, when deepening the structure; these should be interlayed by curly brackets: [{[{[ .. Your input file is wrong. Just see the output exaple, you stated yourself: It follows the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This spec should work for you:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Features": {
        "rows": {
          "*": {
            "*": "Features[&1].@(3,fields[&].name)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Notes:

- I assume your input should look more like:
  `"Features" : { ... }` not  `"Features": []` as pointed out by [@Franta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8120775/franta)
- Checkout the https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ where you can find the examples of the operators used in the snippet above
- Also checkout the [shiftr docs](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java) where you can find more info about the `*`, `&` and `@` operators and their advanced versions

To make it easier to understand while reading the docs:
[image: shift operation explanation]

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, no googling?

Seriously, a sequence of [[[ ? Try i.e. this validator: [codebeautify.org/jsonviewer](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer)

So: Invalid JSON input. The validator says: *E2 ->Error: Parse error on line 1: Parse error on line ^ Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'*

The result:

> Parse error on line 3:
> ...
> "fields": [
> {
>
> ----------------------^
> Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'

Mistake in the syntax in the input: Consecutive square brackets [[[ are wrong, when deepening the structure; these should be interlayed by curly brackets: [{[{[

Just see the output example, you stated yourself: It follows the rule.

Comment: sorry, i tried lot of things but i didnt add my spec here cos the answer was not even close. :(